# Bash shell script getting input from user in a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing bash shell script and I am performing an action that displays a message to the user waiting for his input:

```
(0) 09:41:02 192:~$ eqagent wipe
This command will stop the agent and reset its configuration.
Any configured target or sources will be permanently deleted.
Are you sure? (type YES to continue)
```

How can I make it automatically answer YES in my script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real sure if this is what you're looking for but off the top of my head, maybe something like this?

```
read -t 0 -p 'are you sure ' answer
    case answer in
        *) echo "yes"
    esac
```

`read -t 0` means timeout after 0 seconds. Depending on what you're trying to do, you may want to raise the number of seconds before timeout.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a force flag e. g. - f   with the command. Please check manual.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of `eqagent` this may work

```
eqagent wipe << END
YES
END
```

Or for better control of non-standard situations check `expect`.